# Different interval time between BLE device advertising and the callback from startScan of android phone

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I use android phone to detect a beacon using startScan method, the interval time of beacon adversing is 800ms, but I got the beacon data from callback of startScan every 3~10 seconds. My expectation is I can get the data every 1 second.

Below is my codes. So is there any other ways to get my expectation. Or someone can explain why the interval time is not the same as the adversing time ?

```java
 ScanSettings.Builder builder = new ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY);

    // scan filters has been set the right value.
    bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanFilters, builder.build(), scanCallback);
```

Comment: You can try [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle). One of the best library for BLE in Android

Answer (score 2):

Nothing about the code shown is a problem.  I can confirm your expectation is met with equivalent code in other apps on other devices.  This suggests a problem with :

1. Your BLE device not advertising as often as you expect
2. Your Android phone (possible but unlikely)
3. Some other aspect of your code that you did not show in your question.

Is you BLE device a beacon?  If so, I suggest:

1. Install [BeaconScope](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgyoungtech.beaconscanner) on the same phone, scan for your beacon, then check the PPS rating (Packets Per Second -- scan for at least 30 seconds until the measurement stabilizes).  If you see a value of 0.1-0.3 then the problem is NOT with your code and must be (1) or (2). If you see a much higher PPS value, the problem is with some other aspect of your code not shown.
2. Use a second Android phone with BeaconScope as a transmitter and transmit a beacon at the 10 Hz default rate.  Does your app get a packet every 100-200ms?  If so, you have confirmed the problem is with your BLE device not transmitting as much as you expect.

If your BLE device is not a beacon you can at least perform the second test.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to use 'SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY' mode only hen the application is running in the foreground.

Incase you are in background, you can run a sticky foreground service and set a periodic frequency of 1 sec for your service.

Also scanning Ble for every 1 sec might be extremely heavy for the app.

Comment: My app does not scan every 1 sec.  I just want to get  every package of the device broadcast data which sent every 800ms.